# pressure equation canonical ensemble

Tags: thermodynamics

I have found the following equation for the pressure in an N-particle system in the canonical ensemble:

$p=k_{B}T\frac{N}{V}-\langle \frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\rangle $

Can someone tell me the specific name of that expression? I know it is somehow connected to the Virial theorem, but not exactly the same?

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure it has a name, but I know it can be derived in a few ways. In the framework of statistical mechanics, for example, you can write down the canonical (configurational) partition function of the system in this way:

\begin{equation}
Q = \frac{1}{N!}\int_V d^{3N}R \exp^{-\beta H(\lbrace R\rbrace )} = \frac{V^N}{N!}\int_v d^{3N}r \exp^{-\beta U(\lbrace r\rbrace , V)}
\end{equation}

where the small $r$ are the so-called *reduced* coordinates: if the volume $V$ is a box of side $L$, then $\vec{r} = \vec{R} / L$ (and $v$ is just a box with edges of length unity). Note that now the energy function $U$ depends explicitly on $V$. Now we write the Helmholtz free energy:

\begin{equation}
\beta F = -N \log V + N \log N - N - \log \left( \int_v d^{3N}r \exp^{-\beta U(\lbrace r\rbrace , V)} \right)
\end{equation}

Now we derive the free energy to get the pressure:

\begin{equation}
P = -\frac{\partial F}{\partial V} = k_B T \frac{N}{V} + k_B T \frac{\partial}{\partial V} \log \left( \int_v d^{3N}r \exp^{-\beta U(\lbrace r\rbrace , V)} \right)
\end{equation}

Now we derive the last term of the rhs and use the definition of average in statistical mechanics to obtain:

\begin{equation}
k_B T \frac{\partial}{\partial V} \log \left( \int_v d^{3N}r \exp^{-\beta U(\lbrace r\rbrace , V)} \right) = -\frac{\int_v d^{3N}r \frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\exp^{-\beta U(\lbrace r\rbrace , V)}}{\int_v d^{3N}r \exp^{-\beta U(\lbrace r\rbrace , V)}} = -\frac{\partial \langle U \rangle}{\partial V}
\end{equation}

which should answer your question. I have been a bit sloppy with the notation, but I hope you won't mind :)

Answer (score 0):

This equation also arises is classical thermodynamics from the following:
$$dU=TdS-PdV=T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_VdT+\left[T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_T-P\right]dV$$
So, $$\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_T=\left[T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_T-P\right]$$
But, from one of the Maxwell relationships, $$\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_T=\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_V$$

Therefore, $$\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_T=\left[T\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_V-P\right]$$